# Is it possible to extend an Indian business visa from India?

Tags: india, business-travel, visa-extensions, egyptian-citizens

I'm an Egyptian girl from Cairo. I'm planning a six-month trip to India in December for training purposes, but getting a six-month visa is so hard from my country.

If I can only get 3 months instead of 6 months, is it possible to extend the business visa in India?

Comment: Have you applied for either a business visa (if the company is outside of India) or an employment visa (if the project/contract/company is inside India)?

Answer (score 1):

While the [Embassy of India in Egypt](http://www.eoicairo.gov.in/eoi.php?id=Obtain) does note that *[t]he duration of stay in India, for each visit on a tourist visa or business visa is normally for a period of three months only,* it goes on to add that only a tourist visa is non-extendable.

A business visa, valid for 5 years and multi-entry, may be extended while in the country, according to the [Government of India](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/index.html#).

A business visa extension has to be granted initially by the [Ministry of Home Affairs](https://mha.gov.in/), after which it can be done through a [Foreigners’ Regional Registration Office (FRRO)](https://boi.gov.in/content/frro-contact-list).